# Setting value to static property after throwing an exception

Tags: c#, exception, properties, static

I have this below static property:

```
private static _field;
public static MyProperty
{
    get
      {
         if(_field !=null)
            {
               return _field;
            }
          else
            {
               throw new NullReferenceException();
            }
       }
    set
       {
           _field=value;
       }
}
```

Now I access this property before `_field` is initialised and hence an exception is thrown. Now when I try to set a value for this property, it still throws exception. Now how can I set value to this property after an exception has been thrown from its `get` call?

Comment: Could you show the code that fails?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. When I do `MyProperty = someObject;` it doesn't throw an exception. So the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: I agree with Jon. Please give us the codes so that we can take a look at how you're trying to use the MyProperty class.

Comment: You're probably calling the getter _again_?

Comment: It's against best practice to throw in a property getter: `Avoid throwing exceptions from property getters.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx

Comment: Sorry all, I have found out which bit of code the trouble. In my actual code, apart from setting value to _field, some other fields were also being set and one of them was throwing the exception. Unfortunately, both these exceptions were null reference exceptions, so got a bit confused. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is not thrown when you "try to set the value", only when you try to read it when it's not initialized.

In my opinion [it's not best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx) to raise an exception from the  get accessor of a property. You should return a default value then or initialize the field with the default value before you return it. That would avoid such problems.

I assume something like this causes your issue, somewhere:

```
if(MyProperty == SomeValue) // --> your custom  exception was already thrown
{
    // you never get here
}
```

You could do it in this way:

```
private static _field;
public static MyProperty
{
    get
    {
         if(_field ==null)
         {
               _field = defaultValue;
         }
         return _field;
    }
    set
    {
         _field=value;
    }
}
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx):

> Avoid throwing exceptions from property getters. Property getters
>   should be simple operations without any preconditions. If a getter
>   might throw an exception, consider redesigning the property to be a
>   method. This recommendation does not apply to indexers. Indexers can
>   throw exceptions because of invalid arguments